# Escape HTML tags when converting c# view model to javascript model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, encode

I'm trying to convert the C# Model in razor to javascript model using JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

```
var brandsCollectionModel = '@(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))';
```

The Model contains a number of properties of a different type.
The problem is that some of these properties contain special characters, such as "<, >".

Unfortunately this causes javascript syntax error:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
I'm trying to find a way to detect a property that contains special characters and encode it. 
I'm using Html.Raw to prevent encoding as I don't want to escape double quotes that are generated when converting Model to JSON string.

I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: can you try this: var data = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';
var jsObj = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the serialized Model to js variable.

```
var data = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';
```

When the Model is Serialized to Json, it contains &quot  instead of " character. So replace it with ", parse it and assign to js variable.

```
var jsObj = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```